# Magento2.3 Product Add to Wishlist Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page?

Tags: magento2.3, wishlist, form-key

I am using php 7.2.13 version and magento 2.3 latest version in xampp.
When i do add to wishlist and save anything am getting Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page? this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Change your **Baseurl** and **Baseurl secure** to **`127.0.0.1`** instead of **`localhost`**

   > run **`cache:flush`**
2. Or delete all directories below  **`var/cache`**

Answer (score 0):

Life saver. This worked for me. It also solved my other problem of getting a blank admin panel page. I am testing a fresh install of **Magento 2.1.3 on WAMP**.

Other fixes I needed to make it work on **WAMP**:

> \wamp64\www\\vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\Template\File\Validator.php

Changes at line 138:

```
    //$realPath = $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path);
    $realPath = str_replace('\\', '/', $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path));
```

- ROOT > var > cache > *DELETE ALL*
- ROOT > var > page_cache > *DELETE ALL*
- ROOT > var > session > *DELETE ALL*

> \wamp64\www\\app\etc\di.xml

Replace:

```
<item name="view_preprocessed" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink</item>
```

With:

```
<item name="view_preprocessed" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy</item>
```

So many answers difficult to get answers that work for you. WAMP related answers were difficult to find for 2.3.1.

Besides, it is so hard to get Magento 2.x versions to work straight away. Still struggling to make it work on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Try using docker instead of wamp

Answer (score 0):

This problem is occurred after adding more custom options so because php.ini file not allowed to add more custom options.

So, we need to change default settings of php.ini file.

If php version 7.1 then,

/etc/php/7.1/apache2/php.ini

If php version 7.0 then,

```
/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini
```

If php version 7.2 then,

```
/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini
```

Uncomment this value and update this all value in php.ini,

```
max_input_vars = 200000
max_input_time = 600
max_execution_time = 3600
```

Then Restart Apache 2 web server, and check it.

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

If its any help for future lurkers

I had this issue happening in prod, tried every single link in Google - didn't work

**What worked?**

Seems that the `form_key` cookie was being added the `httpOnly` flag by an apache config adding that flag to all cookies

Once I removed the `httpOnly` for the `form_key` cookie everything worked as it should!