# Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3

While trying to login in default theme of Magento 2.3 Front-end after input of all details "INVALID FORM KEY error is coming up"

PLEASE HELP!!

Comment: this might be the same issue with this one https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/256353/magento2-3-product-add-to-wishlist-invalid-form-key-please-refresh-the-page/256357#256357

Comment: Hey it actually worked... Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 9):

Check your **Baseurl** and **Baseurl secure**

**Change From :-**

> localhost

**To** :-

> 127.0.0.1

**Then Run This Command :-**

```
sudo php bin/magento cache:flush

sudo php bin/magento cache:clean
```

In local this will definitely solve the issue.

**OR Execute Query in Database:-**

```
DELETE FROM core_config_data WHERE path='web/cookie/cookie_domain';
```

Comment: Thanks, It works for me in local server. But I want to solve it from my staging server https://magento-331546-1017597.cloudwaysapps.com. so any help?

Answer (score 2):

1. Change your **Baseurl** and **Baseurl secure** to **`127.0.0.1`** instead of **`localhost`**

   > run **`cache:flush`**
2. Or delete all directories below  **`var/cache`**

:posting this as everyone is posting their own answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear cache by CLI command `php bin/magento cache:flush` and reset your cookies

Comment: Tried the code in CMD. no luck still the same.
How to reset cookies ? 
i have been using these codes till now
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento indexer:reindex