# After update to Magento 2.3.4 there are few errors thrown

Tags: magento2.3.4

[image]

As you can see in the image these errors appear on load.

I tried changing max_input_vars to 200000 in php.ini file. But the issue persists.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/264921/68018

Answer (score 0):

Run compile command to show the error.

I have upgrade Magento version 2.4.3 and face many errors and errors found using compile command

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Comment: Nope, compile command runs without problems.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution [here](https://gitmemory.com/issue/magento/magento2/33748/897764144).

Run these two commands:

```
bin/magento config:set system/security/max_session_size_admin 0

bin/magento config:set system/security/max_session_size_storefront 0
```

Apparently, it removes the limit for session size.